# How to implement Ford-Fulkerson in the specific problem?

Tags: algorithm, adjacency-list, max-flow, ford-fulkerson

I am working on a specific exercise and I am stuck.

To solve:

> Solve the circulation demand problem. There are some factories that produce goods and some villages where the goods have to be delivered. They are connected by a networks of roads with each road having a capacity for the maximum amount of goods that can flow through it. The problem is to find if there is a circulation that satisfies the demand. This problem can be transformed into a maximum-flow problem.
>     Assume that every factory node fi has a production rate pi. In addition, that di is the demand rate of village vi. Your input will be the graph given using an adjacency list for each node of it. Initially give a number describing the number of nodes of the graph and then one line for the adjacency list of each node (together with the capacities) e.g. “d a 10 c 5” means that node d is connected to a (with capacity 10) and to c (with capacity 5). Finally give the production rates for each node (where there are factories) and after that the demand rates for the villages again on each node.

As I have understood I need an input file like this:

```
10
a b 10 c 20
b c 5 d 10
d e 7 f 8
a 10
e -5

//nodes = 10  
//directed graph -> a to b with capacity 10, a to c with capacity 20  
//a production = 10, e consumption = -5
```

I have concluded that I should use the Ford-Fulkerson Algorithm to find the maximum flow (since that's what is requested as the output)

Looking around at different implementations of the algorithm (I am considering using C or Java to code it), I have stumbled upon the following issue:

Ford-Fulkerson works only with 1 source and 1 sink. In this problem we have test-cases where there are 3 factories for example and 2 villages. Can someone enlighten me because I am really stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most optimal way to solve multiple-source multiple-sink flow network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43213410/most-optimal-way-to-solve-multiple-source-multiple-sink-flow-network)

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical extension of the 1-source 1-sink Ford-Fulkerson algorithm. In essence, you consider another "imaginary" node `U` to be the 1 source, and connect that node `U` to all the factories. (i.e. which are the`K` sources in your problem)

Similarly, you connect all the `M` sinks, which are the villages, to another imaginary sink node `V` that you add to the given graph. Then, when you compute the maximum flow from `U` to `V`, you will have computed the max flow from all the factories to all the villages.

Obviously, the weights of the edges connecting U to factories and the ones connecting villages to `V` should be thought through. In your case, each incoming edge to a factory from `U` should have a weight that is equal to the capacity of that factory. In case of the edges connecting villages to `V`, there does not need to be a bound, so it can be as high as the highest weight in the entire graph, or a practical value which could represent infinity.

Comment: I think I understood the concept. Thanks a lot for this. Since each village has a specific demand though, I don't quite understand your approach regarding connecting them all to the Sink. (since it is demonstrated we have a negative value for each village ex. -5)

Comment: Also, do you have any idea if I can use another algorithm for the specific problem?